# MySQL: Insert 25,000,000 codes into table

Tags: mysql, bigdata, apache-torque

I've got 25,000,000 codes (each code has 8 random literals) to insert into my database. We're running with MySQL and Apache Torque as ORM.

My table simplified looks like this:

```
table_code
id BIGINT, Primary Key (no auto-increment, bc of ORM)
code VARCHAR
```

What is the most efficient way to insert them? I tried this with generating Torque-Objects over night, but since the ID needs to be autoincremental, it takes forever.

Any ideas are much appreciated :) Thank you!

Comment: The most efficient way is not to use the ORM, but raw SQL queries. This applies to any application using an ORM.

Comment: Where does the codes come from? What do you need 25 Mil random strings for?

Comment: Is there an index on `code`?  It makes a _huge_ difference.  Why do you need `id` at all?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the queries that need to reach into the table.

Comment: Just updated my question. I don't have any index on code, just use ID as a PrimaryKey.

Answer (score 2):

Hello I think the best is to use `LOAD DATA INFILE`:

A link explain it's faster here : https://medium.com/@benmorel/high-speed-inserts-with-mysql-9d3dcd76f723

For your table juste do something like this :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/mycodes.csv' INTO TABLE table_code;
```

For more information about this function : 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: +1 This is extremely fast. I'm not sure about generating the autoincrement IDs on the fly, though - might be faster to load all data first, and then create IDs afterwards.

Comment: it will be a bit slower with the auto increment, the best is to test it.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Newer versions have faster index creation.  Anyway, it is virtually no effort to create the `AUTO_INCREMENT` as they are inserted _in this case_.  And it would be a big effort to create the id afterward.

Comment: Thank you @DanielE. Didn't know about that one. I need to check the security settings with the database administrator. Problem still going to be the auto-increment-stuff. Is altering the Primary Key Attribute to auto-increment for this import (and remove it after that) a good idea?

Comment: As said before, it won't be so expensive to keep the auto increment